# vagrant-aws: logging with private IP address?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vagrant

I'm using `vagrant-aws` plug-in to provision instances, with both public and private IP  address, in VPC and the plugin seem to use the public IP by defaut, to login to the instance. How can I force Vagrant to use the private IP address instead?

There is `config.ssh.host` setting in Vagrant to login into but in that case is there a way for Vagrant to figure out the private ip of the instance?

Best!!

Answer (score 3):

Though this is an old question it was the first I ran into.  I accidentally fell upon a new vagrant-aws attribute that was added after this question.  It is called "ssh_host_attribute" which you can set to either :public_ip_address, :dns_name, or "private_ip_address".  Here is a link to the doc:
[Omniref vagrant-aws 5.0 docs](https://www.omniref.com/ruby/gems/vagrant-aws/0.5.0/symbols/VagrantPlugins::AWS::Config/ssh_host_attribute%5B%5D).

I added it to my Vagrantfile it like so:

```
aws.ssh_host_attribute = :private_ip_address
```

and it worked flawlessly.  I will next test the :dns_name attribute because I am hoping that will use either the public ip if outside ec2 or the private ip if inside ec2.  That would be perfect for my situation.

Hope this helps someone else searching for this answer.